# Xcode message when building code "This app could not be installed at this time."

Tags: ios, xcode, virtualbox, macos-catalina

I'm new to Xcode. I have downloaded Catalina 10.15 on VirtualBox it's working perfectly fine. But when I try to build and run Xcode project, This Xcode message appears "This app could not be installed at this time". I have seen other people asking the same question and tried the solutions but it didn't work.

*Here is the details of error;*

```
Details
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain error -102.)
Domain: LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain
Code: -102
User Info: {
    CFBundleIdentifier = "DevUraz.Deneme";
    Error = RegistrationFailed;
    "_LSFunction" = "-[_LSInstaller _doinstallApplication:atURL:withOptions:installType:notificationJournaller:reply:]";
    "_LSLine" = 627;
}
--
```

*And sometimes simulator(I'm using simulator of iPhone 11 pro) gives errors too like;*

**com.apple.migrationpluginwrapper quit unexpectedly**

**springboard quit unexpectedly**

*Here is the Simulator.log:*

[Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH2Yb.png)

[Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moDF1.jpg)

[Screen Shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXA63.png)

I couldn't find any solutions for that problem sadly.

Comment: Hey! Can you go into a little more detail about the issue? I haven't worked extensively with VirtualBox but I have a MacBook so I might be of help..?

Comment: I'm wondering why it's saying "app could not be installed" — it sounds like it's talking about Xcode itself, not just the project. Do you have coordinating files on your Desktop for your Xcode projects?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and disabling AVX/AVX2 solved for me.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0
```

Make sure to shutdown the VM and close Virtualbox before and replace "YourVMName" with the actual name of your VM in VirtualBox